# Publishing a browser extensions that links to torrent sites

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, torrent

I'm writing a simple browser extension/add-on that modifies a popular website by adding links to torrent sites next to the content of the original site.

Will my extension be taken down (and my account banned) if I publish the extension on the: a) [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) and b) [Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) site?

I see both sites allow extensions that deal with torrents, but I don't see any extensions that target specific non-torrent sites. (There are extensions that, for example, allow easier interaction with torrent-sharing sites.)

Can legal actions be taken against me for linking to torrent sites? Additional info: I live in the EU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't deal with programming but third-party policies that can only be clarified by lawyers and/or said third parties.

Comment: I talked to a AMO Reviewer on moz irc #amo-editors channel, this addon is acceptable. No legal action, you are just linking.

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart. In the meantime I found an extension on the Chrome Web Store which is similar to what I had in mind. The extension is there since at least 2014, so I guess that kind extensions are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted my extension to https://addons.mozilla.org and it was declined. It looks like these kind of "pirate" extensions/add-ons are not allowed on the official *Add-ons for Firefox* site.

The email I received said:

> Comments: This version did not pass the review because of the
>   following issues:
>
> 1) Per our content policies, we cannot accept add-ons which are
>   related to download of movie or other copyrighted material via
>   Magnet/Torrent or similar means. For more information, please read
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Reviews#Content
>
> Please fix them and submit again. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share a link to your addon, I'll discuss it with the team.

Comment: @Noitidart The add-on listing URL is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-pirate-imdb/ although the add-on is not visible there (I'm guessing because its status is _Incomplete_). The add-on is named "The Pirate IMDb".

Comment: I'll get to this in 24 hours, if i don't please get back to me for a reminder.

Comment: I heard back from a review and it seems this won't work :( - "That addon is NOT allowed

Torrent addons are allowed ONLY if they are general torrent addon

That addon ads torrent links to IMDB movies which are copyrighted

In fact anything to do with thepiratebay.org is not allowed

Personal torrent however is not illegal... that means torrent links that are NOT moives, music or simialr copyrighted (and heavily prosecuted) material" You can petition with the admins though by email `amo-admins@mozilla.org`, they are very nice.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I'll probably try the Chrome Web Store next. Or I'm just gonna publish the extensions on GitHub with install instructions.

Comment: Let me know how it goes with CWS. Also if you do email amo-admins@mozilla.org I'm very interested to hear what they say I think they might approve it.